# Python get file path from a file descriptor int (as returned from os.open)

Tags: python, fdopen

I am using fusepy and I need to convert a file descriptor back in to a file object so that I can obtain the original file path

From the fusepy examples, when a file is created, a file descriptor is returned - for example:

```
def open(self, path, flags):
    print("open:", path)
    return os.open(path, flags)
```

the returned result is an integer: `<class 'int'>` with the value of `4`

in a separate function named write, I need to reverse the file descriptor back in to a file so that I can get the file path, so I tried this:

```
f = os.fdopen(fh)
```

When I check the type of `f` I get the following `f is type: <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>`

Which is not quite what I was expecting but a quick `dir(f)` shows that it has a `name` property, I thought that's what I was looking for, except `name` is simply the number `4`...

How can I get the original file path the descriptor points to?

Comment: You could access the underlying objects through `f.buffer` and `f.buffer.raw`, but you still wouldn't get to the name. Not very portable, but at least if on Linux and (I presume at least some) other U\*X like systems, a way around could be to ask OS directly, e.g. through procfs structures: `os.readlink(f"/proc/self/fd/{fh}")` in your example.

Comment: @OndrejK. that'll do nicely - thank you; I didn't realise `/proc/self` was a thing either, so +1 for that too (I was at this point prior to your answer `os.readlink("/proc/"+str(pid)+"/fd/"+str(fh))` but your example is much cleaner)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since this seems to satisfy the need, I'll post it as an answer for the time being. One could access underlying objects through `f.buffer` and `f.buffer.raw` (not the surprise mentioned in question depends a bit on Python version used, in v2 this looked different), but that still won't help accessing the filename used top open the file. Note: this could have just as well taken place in a calling process and a descriptor could have been inherited by the python process.

Not sure if there is a nicer and more portable way, but one can query OS and on U*X like system a readily available way would be to reference `procfs` structure, namely for the above example:

```
os.readlink(f"/proc/self/fd/{fh}")
```

Still not an entirely trivial question. Descriptor may still be open and used, while the underlying file(name; filesystem reference) has already been deleted.